# Best Memory Cache technique

Tags: android, caching, bitmap

I have been going through the android developer site for [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

But I am confused with the below statement and need suggestions for a good memory cache technique. Below is the link.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

> Note: In the past, a popular memory cache implementation was a
>   SoftReference or WeakReference bitmap cache, however this is not
>   recommended. Starting from Android 2.3 (API Level 9) the garbage
>   collector is more aggressive with collecting soft/weak references
>   which makes them fairly ineffective. In addition, prior to Android 3.0
>   (API Level 11), the backing data of a bitmap was stored in native
>   memory which is not released in a predictable manner, potentially
>   causing an application to briefly exceed its memory limits and crash.

So **is LRU Cache , the best technique than weak reference/Soft reference and why is it so?** Also how to manage same for the different android device versions?

Please help me and suggest the best technique for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the document does not mention this . we do not handle the overhead of cache or recycling bitmaps **it is handeled by using third party[trusted and widely used] tools like picasso or glide or universal image loader**. please read upon this its good to know but a lot of apps use these

Answer (score 1):

About references

A **SoftReference** should be cleared and enqueued as late as possible, that is, in case the VM is in danger of running out of memory.

A **WeakReference** may be cleared and enqueued as soon as is known to be weakly-referenced.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) for more

Using LRU Cache: Why is it preferred, Simple answer is because it's part of android. It is prefered to use the LRU cache as a part of android best practices.

Check this [Android best practices](http://www.slideshare.net/AmgadMuhammad/android-performance-best-practices)

About versioning: It doesn't depends on android versions (Slightly below 2.3). But it depends on devices(Size of LRU cache vary).

Use this calculation for finding the size iin each device. (Android officially suggest this)

```
int memoryClass= ( ( ActivityManager )context.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE ) ).getMemoryClass();
int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memoryClass/ 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are using in displaying the bitmaps ? if you are using libraries such  volley , picasso, universal image loader and others then they handled casching in a good way . if your not using those libraries there is `HttpResponseCache`. but honestly I have never tested for Bitmaps